# Roo hidden field in Jspx

Tags: spring-roo

I want to have a hidden field in a jspx file.

What I would like to do is automatically save the name of the authentificated user in the database. Here is how I do it :

Modify my bean with  :

```
 public void Got.setUserkt(String userkt) {
        final String currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        this.userkt = currentUser;
    }
```

Looking around I found out that i had to use render="false" in my create.jspx page but when render is set to false, no data from my input field is saved in my database.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will resume what I did, for my fellow rookies.

**First step : Cut my method from my roo controler (EntityController_Roo_Controller.aj)**

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String create(@Valid Got got, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            uiModel.addAttribute("got", got);

            addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);

            return "gots/create";

        }

        uiModel.asMap().clear();

        got.persist();

        return "redirect:/gots/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(got.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);

    }
```

**Second Step : Paste the methode into the java contoller (EntityController.java)**

**Third Step : Edit the method to get the usernmae and to modifiy my method with it**

1. added Principal principal as a
   parameter
2. update my entity :
   got.setUserkt(principal.getName());

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)

   ```
   public String create(@Valid Got got, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Principal principal) {

       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

           uiModel.addAttribute("got", got);

           addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);

           return "gots/create";

       }

       uiModel.asMap().clear();

       got.setUserkt(principal.getName()); 

       got.persist();



       return "redirect:/gots/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(got.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);

   }
   ```

Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create an aspect which intercepts saving target entity and adds corresponding field or override corresponding method in Spring Controller in ITD by copying it right to *.java controller and adding field there?

Comment: Tell me, could i find a nice tutorial about such a method ?

Comment: I can't find a tutorial but I found [this link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100109-can-i-override-the-method()-in-controller-OR-domain). So just select target method in target Controller's ITD (file called `XxxController_Roo_Controller.aj`) and perform `Push In` refactoring for it (should be available in Eclipse). Then open your `XxxController.java` and perform your entity modification before saving (as in your code snippet). Remember you should perform it with Roo console running. About my first advice (creating aspect) just read something about AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of disableFormBinding and type should work, as below.

Note: Not sure if it's designed like this :)

Comment: field:input disableFormBinding="true" type="hidden"